# global variable not updated when using namespace in javascript d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, global-variables

So Im building a set of functions to call inside a page. They all reside inside a file "seeingPlotFunc.js" and I call it and some of the functions inside the body of the html file. There are dome global empty arrays declared at the beginning, but when the functions that update them are called, they still return empty:

relevant code in seeingPlotFunc.js:

```
var seeingPlot = seeingPlot || {};

seeingPlot.jsondata1 = [];

seeingPlot.initialData = function () {
d3.json(seeingPlot.initialphp1, function(error1, data1) {
    // after getting the data it's parsed into array
    data1.forEach(function(d){
        d.date = seeingPlot.parseDate(d.date);
        d.f_tok = +d.f_tok;
        seeingPlot.jsondata1.push(d);
    })
})
}
```

and the relevant code in the html file:

```
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src="JS/seeingPlotFunc.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 seeingPlot.initialData();
 console.log(seeingPlot.jsondata1);
</script>
</body>
```

and it returns an empty array. If I call it just after pushing all the data into the array it returns the proper value. I've been banging my head with this one for some LONG hours...

Comment: could it be that on d3.json(seeingPlot.initialphp1, function(error1, data1) data1 and error1 are not new but expected variables that should be called error and data???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function in d3.json gets called asynchronously. So you need wait for a callback function and only then will you get your array.

```
seeingPlot.initialData = function (OnComplete) {
d3.json(seeingPlot.initialphp1, function(error1, data1) {
        // after getting the data it's parsed into array
        data1.forEach(function(d){
            d.date = seeingPlot.parseDate(d.date);
            d.f_tok = +d.f_tok;
            seeingPlot.jsondata1.push(d);
        })
        OnComplete();
    })
}
```

And your HTML

```
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
     src="JS/seeingPlotFunc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    seeingPlot.initialData(function ()
    {
        console.log(seeingPlot.jsondata1);
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Right you are, it needs a callback. Thanks! I'll close this as soon as I post how specifically solved it, but it may take a while.